# zsh ssh autocomplete Host instead of Hostname from ~/.ssh/hosts

Tags: ssh, zsh, autocomplete, hostname

Is there a way I can massage my `~/.zshrc` to make the ssh auto-completion autocomplete for the `Host`, not the `Hostname`?

I have an entry in my `~/.ssh/config` that looks like this:

```
Host staging-rfc staging
  User crmpicco
  Hostname staging.rfc.crmpicco.co.uk
```

If I type `ssh sta[TAB]` then it pre-fills the full hostname of `staging.rfc.crmpicco.co.uk`, which gives me a permission denied error - presumably because it's trying to login with my terminal user and not "crmpicco".

`rfcpicco1872@staging.rfc.crmpicco.co.uk: Permission denied (publickey).`

My `~/.zshrc`:

```
# Highlight the current autocomplete option
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors "${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}"

# Better SSH/Rsync/SCP Autocomplete
zstyle ':completion:*:(scp|rsync):*' tag-order ' hosts:-ipaddr:ip\ address hosts:-host:host files'
zstyle ':completion:*:(ssh|scp|rsync):*:hosts-host' ignored-patterns '*(.|:)*' loopback ip6-loopback localhost ip6-localhost broadcasthost
zstyle ':completion:*:(ssh|scp|rsync):*:hosts-ipaddr' ignored-patterns '^(<->.<->.<->.<->|(|::)([[:xdigit:].]##:(#c,2))##(|%*))' '127.0.0.<->' '255.255.255.255' '::1' 'fe80::*'

# Allow for autocomplete to be case insensitive
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' 'm:{[:lower:][:upper:]}={[:upper:][:lower:]}' \
  '+l:|?=** r:|?=**'

# Initialize the autocompletion
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit -i
```

Comment: Zsh looks for both `Host` and `Hostname` to find completions. But for some reason, if a host name matches, it doesn't try a host alias. The culprit is the code at the beginning of `_ssh_hosts`.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Hmmm, where is the `_ssh_hosts` section?

Comment: In `Completion/Unix/_ssh`

Comment: This is a very silly behavior. The TAB completion looks up and completes the Hostname to the command line, then ssh tries to look the provided string only in the Host entries... I don't see where it is useful at all to autocomplete to Hostnames as they are exact addresses. If I know the exact address I'm not sure I need the ssh config entry in most of the cases (except when it has non-default ports or other switches).

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' so I need to add a `HostAlias` to my ssh config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing my `zstyle` to the following worked perfectly:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:(ssh|scp|ftp|sftp):*' hosts $hosts
zstyle ':completion:*:(ssh|scp|ftp|sftp):*' users $users
```

Comment: This still autocompletes to entries in the Hostname